# Angular JS: Updating $Scope.Array through user input

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, data-binding

I have created a simple angular application - which holds an array of strings.

On the front end - there is a single text input field - which when submitted, calls a function which should push this input to the $scope.array.

All values of the $scope.array are output on the same page, below the text input area.

I would like for the latest inputs to be displayed with the rest of the array value outputs on the front end - in essence, working an example of 2 way binding with angular.

However, when I submit the input value, the output is not updated on the front end - and I do not see why. Please find an example of the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <title>First app - CRUD</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <style></style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="header" align="center">
            <h1>CRUD Application v1</h1>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller="ctrl1" class="main">

            Name: <input type="text" ng-model="players.name">
            <button  ng-click="updateValue()">submit data</button>
            <br><br>

            <p>{{players.name}}</p>


            <p ng-repeat="player in players" ng-model="players.name" class="main">
                {{player.name}}
            </p>


        </div>

</body>


var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('ctrl1', function ($scope){

    //$scope.name = ' ';

    //$scope.players = {"alonso", "gerrard"};

    $scope.players = [{name:'alonso'}, {name:'gerrard'}];


    $scope.updateValue = function(players){

        // take input value and add to collection.
        // send collection via ajax to server


        $scope.players.push(players.name);
        $scope.name = '';

    };

});
```

Further to this - is it recommended to work directly with JSON objects or arrays when using angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to define a $scope variable for the input box and add push the value to the **`name`** property of the player object,

**Controller**

```
  $scope.players = [{
    name: 'alonso'
  }, {
    name: 'gerrard'
  }];
  $scope.newplayer = '';
  $scope.updateValue = function() {
    $scope.players.push({
      name: $scope.newplayer
    });
  };

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="header" align="center">
    <h1>CRUD Application v1</h1>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl1" class="main">
    Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="newplayer">
    <button ng-click="updateValue()">submit data</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>{{players.name}}</p>
    <p ng-repeat="player in players"  class="main">
      {{player.name}}
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSJwudlSqgXidBmH09ek?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to update the updatePlayer Signature, remove the method argument and read it from the ng-model of the input text box.

Here is the modified solution.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.players = [{
      name: 'alonso'
    }, {
      name: 'gerrard'
    }];

    $scope.updateValue = function() {

      $scope.players.push({
        name: $scope.playersName
      });
      $scope.playersName = '';

    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div class="header" align="center">
      <h1>CRUD Application v1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
      Name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="playersName">
      <button ng-click="updateValue()">submit data</button>
      <p ng-repeat="player in players" ng-model="players.name" class="main">
        {{player.name}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```